# How to pass classProperty to LINQ using Expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I have a LINQ query, and I want to pass Person parameters to it. Probably it should be something like this.

```
Expression<Func<Person, long>> exp1 = person.CarId;
Expression<Func<Person, long>> exp2 = person.PetId;

var result = db.people.Select(x => new {PersonName = x.Name, EntityId = exp1}).ToList()
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why did you want to do that? why don't you get value from `x` ?

Comment: I have three almost the same LINQ query, but the difference EntityId. In one query I should get x.CarId in another x.PetId. And I don`t want to write the same code many times.

Comment: Sure there is a way.... but it's MUCH more complicated than writing 3 queries. How about you give us an example that's closer to the complexity of your 3 queries.

Comment: @Daniel You seem like can use judgment in property instead of expression

Answer (score 1):

I've used IQueryble to reuse parts of queries. It was something like the following:

```
var withPets = Get(GetWithPetId);
                
List<WithEntityId> Get(Func<IQueryable<Person>, IQueryable<WithEntityId>> transformer)
{
    transformer(db.People.Where(...))
        .Where( x => x.EntityId > 100)
        .ToList(); 
}

IQueryable<WithEntityId> GetWithPetId(IQueryable<Person> people)
    => people.Select(x => new WithEntityId(x.Name, x.PetId));

IQueryable<WithEntityId> GetWithCard(IQueryable<Person> people)
    => people.Select(x => new WithEntityId(x.Name, x.CarId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla EF do not allow such queries. I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). It needs just configuring `DbContextOptions`:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Then you can use your expressions in the following way:

```cs
var result = db.people
   .Select(x => new {PersonName = x.Name, EntityId = exp1.Invoke(x)})
   .ToList()
```